# using promises with timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

In the context of a Chrome extension, I have to click some links which will cause dynamic menus to be built before revealing the page to the user.

I have to click each link twice, once to show and once to hide. The hide click has to occur in a timeout so that the other script can take over and build the menu.

There are several of these menus to be clicked, so I have created a `do_menu(find,clicks,cb)` function where `find` and `clicks` are jQuery selectors and `cb` is the callback.

From the client end, this looks like:

```
that.do_menu('<seek menu selector>'
            ,'<make menu on click selector>'
            ,function(){that.do_menu('<seek menu selector>'
                                    ,'<make menu on click selector>'
                                    ,function(){that.do_menu('etc'
                                                            ,'etc',ugh!)}
           );}
);
```

At this point I am deciding to put all these selectors into a collection and iterate over them, eventually calling a `done` function. But for the purposes of this discussion, lets say I wanted to implement Promises here.

The snag I am hitting is that I don't know where to go in my timeout. Here is the original function.

```
do_menu:function(find,clicks,cb){
    if($(find).length===0){ // menu needs building
        $(clicks).click(); // show menu
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(clicks).click(); // hide menu
            cb&&cb();
        },100);
    }else{ // menu already built, continue
        cb&&cb();
    }
}
```

When I try to turn this into a function that returns a Promise, I get stuck.

```
do_menu_p:function(find,clicks){
   var that=this;
   return new Promise(function(res,rej){ //  F1!
       if($find).length===0){ // need to build
           $(clicks).click(); // show
           setTimeout(function(){ //         F2!
               $(clicks).click(); // hide
               res({status:'did it'}); // This will not work cuz F1!==F2 ??
           });
       }
   }.bind(that));
}
```

And my client would look like:

```
var that=this;
this.do_menu_p('<menu>','<click>')
.then(/*hmmm...??*/ that.do_menu_p.bind(that,'<more>','<args>'))
```

No, I can tell that isn't right. Yes, I suck at promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the approach of checking if something is done, **only once** after `100ms` as bad practice. Least you could do is check repeatedly. something like:

```
do_menu:function(find,clicks,cb){
    var ctr = 0;
    function check(){
        if($(find).length===0){ // menu needs building
            $(clicks).click(); // show menu
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(clicks).click(); // hide menu
                ctr++;
                if(ctr<10){
                     check();
                }else{
                    //throw some error, to avoid infinite checking.
                }
            },100);
        }else{ // menu already built, continue
            cb && cb();
        }
    }
    check(ctr);
}
```

the same thing with promises

```
do_menu_p:function(find,clicks){
    return new Promise(function(res,rej){
        var ctr = 0;
        function check(){
            if($(find).length===0){ // menu needs building
                $(clicks).click(); // show menu
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(clicks).click(); // hide menu
                    ctr++;
                    if(ctr<10){
                         check();
                    }else{
                        rej(new Error("Menu cannot be built"));
                    }
                },100);
            }else{ // menu already built, continue
                res({status:'did it'});
            }
        }
        check(ctr);
    });
}
```

usage can be:

```
var that=this;
this.do_menu_p('<menu>','<click>')
.then(function(res){
    return that.do_menu_p('<more1>','<args1>'));
}).then( function(res){
    return that.do_menu_p('<more2>','<args2>'));
}).catch( errorHandler);
```

Long story short, basically, the `then` takes two functions as attributes, (successCallback, errorCallback) of the said Promise.
  And you can chain promises by returning new promise at end of each promise.

### Edit:

#### A simple [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a93va9du/)

not sure if below method is the right way to do it, you can give it a try...

```
do_menu_p:function(array){

    if(!array || array.length<2) return;
    function innerPromFn(i){
        var find = array[i], clicks = array[i+1];
        return new Promise(function(res,rej){
            var ctr = 0;
            function check(){
                if($(find).length===0){ // menu needs building
                    $(clicks).click(); // show menu
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(clicks).click(); // hide menu
                        ctr++;
                        if(ctr<10){
                             check();
                        }else{
                            rej(new Error("Menu cannot be built"));
                        }
                    },100);
                }else{ // menu already built, continue
                    res({status:'did it'});
                }
            }
            check(ctr);
        }).then(function(res){
            i+=2;
            if(i>array.length){
                return res;
            }else{
                return innerPromFn(i);
            }
        });
    }

    return innerPromFn(0);
}
```

Comment: Can you show me how to do this in an array fashion, something involving `map` or `all`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with. Beats a three-legged donkey. The guts of the checking are left out, I just needed to be able to throttle promises using a timeout.

```
var menus=[{id:0},{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}];

function doer(menu){
    return new Promise(function called(res,rej){
      console.log('click1:'+menu.id);
      setTimeout(function(){
        if(menu.id===2){return rej(new Error('could not'));}
        console.log('click2:'+menu.id);
        res(1);// happy
      },Math.random()*8000);
    });  
}

Promise.reduce(menus,function(ctr,cur,i){
  return doer(menus[i]).then(function(res,rej){
     console.log('happy:',res);
  });
},$.when(1)).then(function(){
  console.log('everyones done'); //no errors
}).catch(function(eee){
  console.log('Error:',eee);
}).finally(function(){
  console.log('finally');
});
```

This is Bluebird if that matters. I don't know the Bluebird equivalent of `$.when(1)`.